# How to batch rename sequentially prefixed numbers to new sequential prefixes via terminal?

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename

How can I batch rename, using the terminal, a set of files where multiple numbers share the same prefix so that all those prefixes are set to new ones?

For example:

```
011.foo.txt   -> 001.foo.txt
011.bar.psd   -> 001.bar.psd
011.baz.gif   -> 001.baz.gif
012.qux.js    -> 002.qux.js
012.corge.png -> 002.corge.png
...
020.thud.txt  -> 010.thud.txt
```

I'd like to use the rename command if possible:

```
rename [ -h|-m|-V ] [ -v ] [ -0 ] [ -n ] [ -f ] [ -d ] [ -e|-E perlexpr]*|perlexpr [ files ]
```

Really appreciate your help figuring this out, Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to simply reduce the numerical value of the prefix by 10 in each case?

Comment: The relationship between your source and target numbers is not clear.  A single invocation of the rename command is not going to be able to make a complex manipulation like this.  A safe approach to something like this would be to generate a file (using awk? perl?) with multiple mv commands and examine the results and edit out any problems, and the run the file.

Comment: @steeldriver that's an interesting solution I hadn't thought of. But ideally I'd like to have the renamed files start at a specific point (eg 001 or 005) without doing the math if possible so that I can use the same solution regardless of the initial number in the current list of files.

Comment: @user10489 Sorry, I made a typo in my example and have updated it (010.thud.txt was previously incorrectly named 003.thud.txt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the perl [`rename`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/prename.1p.html) as requested.

For what your question demonstrates:

```bsh
rename -n 's/^(\d+)/sprintf "%03d", $1-10/e' *
```

dry-run output:

```
rename(011.bar.psd, 001.bar.psd)
rename(011.baz.gif, 001.baz.gif)
rename(011.foo.txt, 001.foo.txt)
rename(012.corge.png, 002.corge.png)
rename(012.qux.js, 002.qux.js)
rename(020.thud.txt, 010.thud.txt)
```

For what the question title says, with actual sequential prefixes:

```bsh
rename -n -E 'use vars q{$n}' -e 's/^(\d+)/sprintf "%03d", ++$n/e' *
```

```
rename(011.bar.psd, 001.bar.psd)
rename(011.baz.gif, 002.baz.gif)
rename(011.foo.txt, 003.foo.txt)
rename(012.corge.png, 004.corge.png)
rename(012.qux.js, 005.qux.js)
rename(020.thud.txt, 006.thud.txt)
```

---

For the first one, if you don't want to hardcode the delta `10`:

```bsh
rename -n -E 'use vars q{$delta}' -e '
    s{^(\d+)}{
        $delta = $1 - 1 unless defined $delta;
        sprintf "%03d", $1 - $delta
    }e
' *
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want files with the same original prefix to map to the same prefix in the new scheme **without** relying on subtraction, then you could do so by creating a hash (associative array) of the prefixes, numbering those sequentially, then performing the rename substitutions by lookup in the hash. Ex.

```
$ rename -n -E '
  BEGIN {
    my $n = 1;
    our %pfxs;
    foreach my $f (@ARGV) {
      $pfxs{$1} = (exists $pfxs{$1} ? $pfxs{$1} : $n++) if $f =~ /^(\d{3})/
    }
  }
  our %pfxs;
  s/^(\d{3})/sprintf "%03d", $pfxs{$1}/e
' [0-9][0-9][0-9].*
rename(011.bar.psd, 001.bar.psd)
rename(011.baz.gif, 001.baz.gif)
rename(011.foo.txt, 001.foo.txt)
rename(012.corge.png, 002.corge.png)
rename(012.qux.js, 002.qux.js)
rename(020.thud.txt, 003.thud.txt)
```

Since it doesn't rely on subtraction, this method can be used even when the original prefixes are non-numeric.

This can undoubtedly be improved - in particular, one could check the max value of `$n` at the end of the mapping and choose the width of the output accordingly.

Comment: Sorry @steeldriver I made a mistake when I typed 003.thud.txt, I actually meant to type 010.thud.txt

Comment: @io4250 tbh I assumed it didn't really matter since we don't have the `...` parts of the sequence

Answer (score 1):

##### In bash

Try this (dry-run) from within the directory containing the files:

```bsh
for f in *
do
    r="${f#*.}"
    p="${f%%.*}"
    if [ "$p" -eq "$p" ] 2>/dev/null
    then  
    p="$((10#$p - 10))"
    p="$(printf "%03d" $p)"
    echo mv -- "$f" "$p.$r"
    fi 
done
```

If you are satisfied with the printed output, then change the line:

```bsh
echo mv -- "$f" "$p.$r"
```

to:

```bsh
mv -- "$f" "$p.$r"
```

removing `echo` to do the actual renaming.